# SQL INSERT from select with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-insert, sap-ase

Good afternoon in my timezone.

i have to insert a row in a table but one of the columns are values from another table.So what i want to accomplish is something like this

```
INSERT TABLE_NAME(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) VALUES("VAL1","VAL2","VAL3",(SELECT COL_A FROM TABLE2 WHERE COL_B = 'X'))
```

But i think the above code is not possible so i use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) 
SELECT "COL1","COL2","COL3", COL_A FROM TABLE2 T2
WHERE COL_B= "X"
```

My question is:
I want to insert values even the select does not return values and in this case the COL4 will be NULL

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot insert a row that is not in the table.

If you are expecting one row (in the case of a match), you can use aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) 
    SELECT "COL1","COL2","COL3", MAX(COL_A)
    FROM TABLE2 T2
    WHERE COL_B = 'X';
```

This will return `NULL` if there is no match -- but only one row even if there are multiple matches in the table.

Comment: shouldn't there be a `GROUP BY` clause for the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @SSteven . . . No.  Without the `GROUP BY`, this is guaranteed to return one row.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from your description, only one column is NULL, other 3 columns have values. You should use Select INTO as https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 INTO TABLE2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_B= "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table to store the primary keys of TABLE2 (for eg TABLE2 has primary key 'X', 'Y')

```
CREATE TABLE #TempPK (COLB int null);

insert into #TempPK(COLB) values ('X');
insert into #TempPK(COLB) values ('Y');
```

--then you do a FULL OUTER JOIN on your insert select from statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) 
    SELECT "COL1","COL2","COL3", MAX(COL_A)
    FROM TABLE2 T2 FULL OUTER JOIN  #TempPK TPK
    ON T2.COL_B = TPK.COLB
```

This way you should be able to insert both rows(X and Y) and the Row X should show NULL values all across the row. Hope it makes sense.